# "You have been explained about the exam" or "You are explained..."

Tags: passive-voice

"Students have been explained about the exam" or "students are explained about the exam".
Google Translate translates both of these sentences to a common single sentence in Hindi.
I am confused which to use.

Comment: Neither sentence makes sense - it is something _about_ the examination which has been explained _to_ the students.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more informative?

Comment: _Explain_ can't take the Passive construction with an indirect object, because it doesn't take the Dative construction: _They explained (about) the exam to the students_ is grammatical, but not *_They explained the students (about) the exam._

Answer (score 1):

It is not the students who have been explained, but some information about the exam which has been explained *to* them.

"Students have been informed about the exam" would be acceptable, but *explain* needs to have as subject the thing which is being explained, not the person receiving the explanation.

The tense used would depend on the context. "The exam has been explained to the students" states that it has already happened.

"The exam is explained to the students" could describe what is happening now, or what usually happens before an exam.